# Error - "Cannot find module ./en.json" using vue-i18n plugin

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, webpack, vue-i18n

I have an existing Vue project, and I'm adding localization to it with the `i18n` plugin. Everything installed properly, and according to everything I've read (see [here](https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-vue-app-with-vue-i18n)), I have everything installed correctly. This includes one file per locale under `/src/locales` with the name of the locale as the file name (`/src/locales/en.json`).

The contents of the `/src/i18n.js` file are:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

Vue.use(VueI18n);

function loadLocaleMessages() {
  const locales = require.context('./locales', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i);
  const messages = {};
  locales.keys().forEach((key) => {
    const matched = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\./i);
    if (matched && matched.length > 1) {
      const locale = matched[1];
      messages[locale] = locales(key);
    }
  });
  return messages;
}

export default new VueI18n({
  locale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE || 'en',
  fallbackLocale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_FALLBACK_LOCALE || 'en',
  messages: loadLocaleMessages(),
});
```

The error I am running into is inside `loadLocaleMessages()`, where it is attempting to load the `/src/locales/.json` files. I stepped through it in a debugger, and at

```
messages[locale] = locales(key);
```

it throws the error

```
Cannot find module './en.json'
```

where `key` = `./en.json` and `locale` = `en`.

As far as I can tell, I'm doing everything correct. What am I missing that is causing this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as embarrassing as it is to admit this, the issue all along was a trailing comma in my `en.json` file. I had

```
{
  "message": "hello i18n !!",
}
```

instead of

```
{
  "message": "hello i18n !!"
}
```

probably because I'm so used to eslint forcing trailing commas in my JS code.

When all else fails, take notice of compilation errors in your IDE...

Comment: thank you for posting the answer! had the same thing today and wouldn't know to suspect a trailing comma!

Comment: No problem, I try to avoid being [this guy](https://xkcd.com/979/).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error but was because I created the Json file but never put any content.

Just in case It also happens to you.